# Help finding a proper method to make roads, tracks, superelevation

Tags: splines

I have some experience with Blender and found it impossible to make optimized roads with proper superelevated corners (road camber/tilt). I looked into Race Track Builder on Steam for track building but there are mixed reviews. What other options do I have?

[image]

Road made using a curve and bevel object (bezier curve). This method shows the superelevation that I want but right-hand corners are tilted the opposite way, but the subdivisions are optimal.

[image]

Road made using array and curve modifier. Easy to do, but this method gives the road a fixed rate of subdivisions and the inside of the corner drops too low no matter how little tilt is added. The tilt is exaggerated to show the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can use GN for this. For example, with this node tree you can adapt the angle to your liking:

[image]

Note: curve twist method should be z-up.

result:

[image]

Note: of course you can finetune the angle also by other math nodes e.g. power or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

I did it just like you but later extruded, added thickness with solidify tool and lifted the solidified parts.
[image]

Edit: of course, after you solidify, just move up only top edges of the parts added with solidify. And your method works great with velodromes.